# passing multiple parameter in jquery function with document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form that is created in jquery and to blur event i want to get the value of the input field. my input text field looks like this.

```
 <td><input type="text" id="strtdt-'+processtype+'-'+i+'" class="form-control" placeholder=""  onblur="getTripInput('+processtype+','+i+')" onchange="changeInputNumberFormat(this);"></td>

<input type="text" id="enddt-'+processtype+'-'+i+'" class="form-control dynamic-input" placeholder=""   onclick="getTripInput('+i+','+processtype+')" onchange="changeInputNumberFormat(this);"></td>
```

this is created in jquery that i am avoiding and it gives me this.

```
<input type="text" id="strtdt-single_yarn-0" class="form-control" placeholder="" onblur="getTripInput(single_yarn,0)" onchange="changeInputNumberFormat(this);">

<input type="number" id="enddt-single_yarn-0" class="form-control" placeholder="" onclick="getTripInput(single_yarn,0)" onchange="changeInputNumberFormat(this);">
```

the onblur event

```
function getTripInput(processType,i){
    var strtdt = document.getElementById('strtdt-'+processType+'-'+i).value;
    var enddt = document.getElementById('enddt-'+processType+'-'+i).value;
    var productionloss = document.getElementById('proloss-'+processType+'-'+i).value;

    alert(strtdt);
    alert(enddt);
    alert(productionloss);
}
```

giving error

```
common.js:1854Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

this points to the `getTripInput() function` first line `var strtdt`

the problem is if i remove any one parameter `i` or `processType` from everywhere `getTripInput()` and also remove from my `input text field` this thing works.

Comment: If you had used `$('#strtdt-'+processType+'-'+i).val()` instead, it at least wouldn't throw if the element wasn't found.

Comment: Also note that your ID is totally invalid as it contains the actual plus signs and single quotes.

Comment: The first code is actually a HTMLString you're appending to the document?

Comment: yes it is generated and appending in the table div

Comment: @adeneo its throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null

Comment: So you want this blur handler to work with the input element itself? Then why not just pass `this` to it, same as with the call to the `changeInputNumberFormat` function in the change handler …?

Comment: it looks like processType and i are not acting like you want them to. Run it again and tell us what those two variables are compared to what you want them to be.

Comment: i have edited my above section its exactly giving me values that i want. however i am not able to pass any 2nd param  @zfrisch

Comment: @black the answer to your question is that you're not passing single_yarn as a string.  onclick="getTripInput('single_yarn',0)"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n8wdtob9/1/

Comment: is i do console.log(i+processType)  in getTripInput() it gives me 0[object HTMLButtonElement]. @zfrisch

Comment: passing only `processType` also giving me error

Comment: @black I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean? I feel like you're going to have to redesign this question at this point. I'm not sure exactly what solution you're looking for or the context this code is in. If you're looking for a way to select elements using a function, it's not too difficult. You're going to want to create the element id as a string and pass it to a function for manipulation. As for my answer, right now it appears as though single_yarn is an undefined variable as opposed to a string, and because of that you can't get it's value because it returns undefined.

Comment: agreed, atleast i can debug now. @zfrisch

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting it because I can see in one input you've used

```
getTripInput(single_yarn,0)
```

And the other one is:

```
getTripInput(0,single_yarn)
```

Is it intentional or a mistake.

For the second one in the getTripInput function it becomes:

```
document.getElementById('strtdt-0-single_yarn').value;
```

Thus it's actually undefined.

Comment: I see. Anyways, is it possible to create some codepen / jsFiddle demo for this? otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: @black : In the jsFiddle example I'm seeing the error for the line document.getElementById('proloss-'+processType+'-'+i) and I'm not seeing the input as well.  So did you missed then input somehow in the html?